# 画面中央（縦・横）に表示したいDIV要素が、左上に表示されてしまう原因・対策を知りたい

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

皆様　いつも大変お世話になっております。ネット上の記事を参考にCLASS名=BOXのDIV要素を、画面中央に表示しようとていますが、JSが正常に機能していないのか左はしに表示されてしまいます。

## 質問

以下がコーディングですが、原因をどなたかご教示頂けませんでしょうか？

ちなみに
①画面の背景色が変わっている、DIV=boxの縦横のサイズを試しにメッセージボックスへ表示してみると、無事表示することができました。（=外部ファイル記述のCSSは参照に成功している）
②画面を開くと一番上に位置するテキストボックスへフォーカスがあたっている、上記のとおり試しにメッセージボックスで縦横のboxのサイズを表示しようとすると無事メッセージボックスが現れてきた。（=外部ファイル記述のJSは参照に成功している）

===HTML(PHP)===

```
<?php include "php_classes/classes.php";
    
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST["loginid"])) {

        // 省略

    }

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>ログイン</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/logon_style.css">
        <!-- Jquery -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/logon.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box">
            <form action="" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="loginid"><br>
                <input type="password" name="password"><br>
                <input type="submit" name="login" value="ログイン">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

===CSS===

```
@charset "UTF-8";

/* タイプセレクタ */
body {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    background-color: #f5f3eb;
    font-family: meiryo ,sans-serif;
}



.box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

===JavaScript(JQuery)===

```
$(function(){
    
    //画面最初のテキストボックスへフォーカスあてる
    $("input[type=text]").eq(0).focus();


    //*** ｂｏｘというクラス名のｄｉｖ要素が真ん中に表示されない！***
    checkWidth = function(){
        var browserWidth = $(window).width();
        var boxW = $(".box").width();
        var plusPxW = ((browserWidth - boxW)/2);
        $('.box').css({'left': plusPxW + "px"});
    };
     
    checkHeight = function(){
        var browserHeight = $(window).height();
        var boxH = $(".box").height();
        var plusPxH = ((browserHeight - boxH)/2);
        $('.box').css({'top': plusPxH + "px"});
    };


    $(function(){
        checkWidth();
        $(window).resize(checkWidth);
    });
     
    $(function(){
        checkHeight();
        $(window).resize(checkHeight);
    });

});
```

Comment: styleの.box へ position: fixed; を追加しましょう。デフォルトはposition: static;です。

Comment: yyz様　いつもありがとうございます。できました。

Comment: コチラの質問は解決致しましたでしょうか？もし解決した場合は自己回答を行い二日後に承認するか、参考になったコメント主に回答として書き直していただいて承認してください。

Comment: Myaku様　対応が遅れ申し訳ございませんでした。またお気づきの点が御座いましたらご指導を頂けましたら幸いです、ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

皆様、ご支援をありがとうございます。
本件、yyz様のご見解から無事解決を導くことができました。

ページ上で中央に表示したかったDIV要素に、CSS側で予め

```
position: fixed;
```

を記述すると、見事期待通りの結果を得ることができました。感謝感激です。